# Change extensions that are recognized as "executable text files"

Tags: scripts, default-programs, nemo

For script files with the extension `.sh` I found it convenient to enable *"Ask each time"* for what to do with executable text files. Now however it also asks it for other types of files (for example Mathematica files `.m`) where I just want to open them with the default editor. Is there a way to change which file extensions are considered *"executable text files"*. I would like to be asked what to do for `.sh` files only.

System:
Ubuntu 20.04, I am using Nemo and not Nautilus as my default file explore so I would like a solution that works with Nemo, but the issue seems to be the same for both explorers.

Comment: Just to clarify: I guess this only happens with any executable file ?! The behavior of Nemo/Nautilus here is about the executable bit, not about the extension, so I'm not sure if it's possible. Definetely a good question!

Comment: See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-behavior.html.en

Comment: @pLumo, well I guess a good related question is why it thinks it is an executable file. I never set that by hand but I guess perhaps Mathematica does that. It contains code and is in that sense executable. Perhaps a solution would be if I can systematically and automatically make all .m files non-executable. (Althought that might bring nasty surprises if it is required for something internally.)

Comment: In Unix/Linux, a file's name has nothing to do with what it is. The executable characteristic is controlled by the file's permission bits. What you did was to turn on "Ask each time" for all executables.

Comment: @waltinator, good point. That of course does not change the desired behavior I want. It probably does change how to achieve it. Also somehow some files are marked as executables and others are not. If this is not done based on the extension it probably actually depends on the program that created the files. Perhaps a solution is to automatically turn off the "executable" permission for all files with a certain extension. I believe that in this case for example the .m file does not actually need the exectuble permission (...)

Comment: ... since the code is always run as a package read from an already running process. It never needs to execute on click.